# Mouse hover event in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, hover, mouseevent, mouse

I am working in MVC and I want to show my data in an asp GridView and I also want to change the row backcolor whenever mouse hover that particular row. Please let me know how can I do that.

Thanks in advance,
gbhatnagar.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript (JQUERY!) and have an on hover event for the row. So when hovered over, you switch the previously highlighted row go back to normal and change the colour of the current row.
You could easily do it with Jquery and by having a row css class and a highlighted row css class.